# Use Compactness Theorem to (dis)prove?

Tags: logic, compactness, first-order-logic

I have Problems understanding this task:

$\tau=\{X_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Prove or disprove that there is a set of first-order sentences $\Phi$, which will be satisfied by an Interpretation $\mathfrak{I}$, if and only if $\mathfrak{I}(Y)=1$ for an infinite set of variables $Y \in \tau$.

Comment: What don't you understand in the task ?

Comment: if i should try to solve it with the compactness theorem. If yes, how to start?

Comment: Something is unclear in your question. How is it possible to relate a set of _first-order_ sentences to a set of _propositional_ variables?